# About JAX-WS Holder NullPointerException

Tags: java, jax-ws, cxf, apache-camel

I am using the near-latest jars of CXF and Camel, when populating the soap request into the Camel route through cxf:bean:ServiceEndpoint, the JAX-WS Holder parameter always return null. I tried to debug through trace stack, and found the Holder's value is null when populating the CXFExchange into the CamelExchange. I wonder how to fix this issue. By the way, everything worked with JAX-WS endpoint.

The itnerface is like this

```
@WebService(name="createSecurityOrder", targetNamespace="http://")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
public interface CreateSecurityOrder {

    @WebResult(name = "Acknowledgment", targetNamespace = "http://")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "createSecurityOrder", targetNamespace
    = "http://", className = "com.ei.CreateSecurityOrder_Type")
    @WebMethod
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "acknowledgment", targetNamespace = "http://")
    public Acknowledgment createSecurityOrder(
        @WebParam(name = "miscellaneous", targetNamespace = "http://")
        PartnerInformation miscellaneous,
        @WebParam(name = "paymentInformation", targetNamespace = "http://")
        PaymentInformation paymentInformation,
        @WebParam(name = "customerInformation", targetNamespace = "http://")
        CustomerInformation customerInformation,
        @WebParam(name = "securityBom", targetNamespace = "http://")
        SecurityBOM securityBom,
        @WebParam(mode = WebParam.Mode.INOUT, name =
        "ENVELOPE_HEADER", targetNamespace = "http://", header = true)
        javax.xml.ws.Holder<EnvelopeHeader> envelopeHeader
    ) throws SecurityOrderException;
}
```

**Order_Type class is like this

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "CreateSecurityOrder", propOrder = {
"miscellaneous",
"paymentInformation",
"customerInformation",
"securityBom"
})
public class CreateSecurityOrder_Type {

@XmlElement(required = true)
protected PartnerInformation miscellaneous;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected PaymentInformation paymentInformation;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected CustomerInformation customerInformation;
@XmlElement(required = true, nillable=false)
protected SecurityBOM securityBom;
```

The cxf configuration is like this

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="createSecurityOrder"
                 address="/createSecurityOrder"
                 serviceClass="com.ei.CreateSecurityOrder">
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

Route configuration is like this

```
from("cxf:bean:createSecurityOrder")
    .routeId("preProcessOrder")
    .wireTap("direct:tap")
    .processRef("validateOrder"));
```

validateOrderBean is like this

```
    public class ValidateOrder implements Processor {

        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            Message in = exchange.getIn();

            List<Object> parameters = in.getBody(List.class);

            // populate parameters
            PartnerInformation partnerInformation = (PartnerInformation)
parameters.get(0);
            PaymentInformation paymentInformation = (PaymentInformation)
parameters.get(1);
            CustomerInformation customerInformation =
(CustomerInformation) parameters.get(2);
            SecurityBOM securityBom = (SecurityBOM) parameters.get(3);
            Holder<EnvelopeHeader> envelopeHeader =
(Holder<EnvelopeHeader>) parameters.get(4);
```

Comment: Some code would be helpful.

Comment: @Peter, some code added, thanks.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://www.sachinhandiekar.com/2014/02/getting-soap-headers-using-camel-cxf.html

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov, that post talks about soapHeaders, while my Holder object is not in the soapHeaders, but in the body, like I said, the Holder object's value get lost during the transformation from CXFExchange to CamelExchange. I did think about this idea before. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @chenrui333 Your code example is overly complex. Please see "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I just wrote a simple test case  http://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/commit/f5849f00  to reproduce the error, but the test is passed.

Comment: @WillemJiang, thanks for the demo, I have found the issue, there are some errors with the request wrapper, that's why the the value get lost during the transition. Before going into the integration test, I have already taken the unit test reference, and passed the unit test. Thanks.